# Invalid API Key hmac python

Tags: python, api, hmac

I'm trying to use the api at https://c-cex.com/ to build a bitcoin trading application for my portfolio and I'm running into an issue with using the private functions that require authentication.  It provides a php example of how to connect and I did my best to recreate it in python but its returning that my key is invalid (though I've copied the apikey straight from my email

```
apikey='141FA9467F8EAC7917A9D6279AD96B4F';
apisecret='6A946F6A331F8CCDFA19EB2D73FD9B1D';
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
nonce= (dt - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()

uri='https://c-cex.com/t/api.html?a=getbalance&currency=BTC&apikey=' + apikey + '&nonce=' + str(nonce);
sign = hmac.new(bytes(apisecret,encoding='utf-8'), uri.encode(encoding='utf-8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {'apisign': sign}

response = requests.get(uri,headers)
print(response.json())
```

and the output that is being returned is

```
{'result': None, 'success': False, 'message': 'APIKEY_INVALID'}
```

The best assumption I can make is that I'm not using the hmac function properly I've tested it with 2 seperate API keys (my actual API key and this testing one in the code that only has access to GET functions)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any answers so I looked through some open source projects that would be doing something similar.

```
 encoding='ASCII'
```

was the answer